Put a New ECM in my Buick Park Avenue year 2002. How do I get the keys to program it?
It is A 2002 Buick Park Avenue. I need to get my keys to be recognized by the ECM

Vats system relearn. Gm vehicle anti theft system. Google it and it will give you instructions on how to reset the system to work with your key

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
